# Heroku creates the DB column with a not null constraint even though that's not in the DB schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I've got a Rails 6 project which has the DB schema below.

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_19_144922) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.bigint "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1
    t.integer "price"
    t.bigint "order_id"
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_order_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "address"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "payment_type_id", null: false
    t.index ["payment_type_id"], name: "index_orders_on_payment_type_id"
  end

  create_table "payment_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "line_items", "carts"
  add_foreign_key "line_items", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "line_items", "products"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "payment_types"
end
```

If I run the project locally everything is fine but if I push it to Heroku then I get a not null violation error as below while trying to create a `line_item` with a `NULL` `order_id`:

```
2021-04-22T21:21:33.736279+00:00 app[web.1]: [3a9004c4-f333-438f-b3f3-fa4e60e36215] ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "order_id" of relation "line_items" violates not-null constraint
```

And doing `\d line_items` on Heroku's DB returns:

```
                                          Table "public.line_items"
   Column   |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                Default
------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('line_items_id_seq'::regclass)
 product_id | bigint                         |           | not null |
 cart_id    | bigint                         |           | not null |
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |
 quantity   | integer                        |           |          | 1
 price      | integer                        |           |          |
 order_id   | bigint                         |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "line_items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_line_items_on_cart_id" btree (cart_id)
    "index_line_items_on_order_id" btree (order_id)
    "index_line_items_on_product_id" btree (product_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_11e15d5c6b" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
    "fk_rails_2dc2e5c22c" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)
    "fk_rails_af645e8e5f" FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES carts(id)
```

So, why do I get a not null constraint for the `order_id` column on Heroku, even though I don't have that in my DB schema? Locally everything is OK.

Comment: 1) are you the only person working on this project?  2) can you do a search on order_id in your migrations dir to see if there isn't some migration changing it?

Comment: Yes, I am. That's just a project from a book that I am following. Nothing fancy. I was just curious why on Heroku that column has a not null constraint even though it doesn't have that and thanks to you I've figured it out! Even though the schema didn't have the constraint, migrations were overwriting it. I hadn't thought about it. Thank you so much! :)